# Determine appropriate version for cmake_minimum_required()

Tags: cmake

From a set of `CMakeLists.txt` files, how can I determine an appropriate version number for `cmake_minimum_required()`? Is there a better way than being familiar with the history of CMake features and using trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

CMake has [per-version documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/) on its website. Using it, you may check that all features you use in your project are supported by a specific CMake version.

Features include command names, command options and their possible values, names of modules shipped with CMake.

Usually project does not need *precise* minimum CMake version. You may take reasonable version, which is accessible for users, and check whether this version supports all features you use.

Comment: `cmake` documentation doesn't go beyond v3.0 though.

Comment: @Cyan: References to documentation for pre-3.0 versions are at the bottom of this page: https://cmake.org/documentation/