# target_link_libraries and INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property

Tags: cmake

In this snippet:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(hello LANGUAGES C VERSION 0.0.1)
add_library(a INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(a INTERFACE /usr/local/include)
add_executable(b main.c)
target_link_libraries(b PUBLIC a)
get_target_property(dirs b INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "dirs: ${dirs}")
```

CMake will print:

```
-- dirs: dirs-NOTFOUND
```

I want **all** include directories of a target, but apparently those added via `target_link_libraries` get ignored somehow. How can I obtain all include directories of a target?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the information you are seeking is only available after the generation step. You can get those only with e.g. [`add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) calls, which run during compile time. Your `get_target_property()` and `message()` calls run during CMake configuration step.

*Disclaimer*: Taken with small modifications from the question linked below:

```
add_custom_command(
    b_lists ALL
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "b INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: $<TARGET_PROPERTY:B,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>"
)
```

**References**

- [Recursive list of LINK_LIBRARIES in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756195/recursive-list-of-link-libraries-in-cmake)
- [target_include_directories prior to 2.8.12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900332/target-include-directories-prior-to-2-8-12)

Answer (score 0):

target_link_libraries does not add any directory, it adds the specific library that you've included. Use make VERBOSE=1 to see the complete command. You might be able to get the library output directory by reading the build directory or the library output name.